# R: Replace values in one table, based on another table

Tags: r, replace

Let‘say I have a TableA:

```
Code Description
001 Apple
002 Banana
```

I also have TableB:

```
Description
001
002
003
```

I want to replace the values in Description of TableB with values from Description of TableA.

I understand that I can do a simple join. But, I would like to replace values. How can I do that?

My possible solution is the following, but it does not work properly:

```
TableB$Description <- TableA[TableA$Code %in% TableB$Description, Description]
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be a merge/join operation,

```r
merge(TableB, TableA, by.x = "Description", by.y = "Code", all.x = TRUE)
#   Description Description.y
# 1           1         Apple
# 2           2        Banana
# 3           3          <NA>
```

(For more info on merge/join, see [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272) and [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3358272.))

Or it could be a simple lookup using `match`:

```r
TableA$Description[ match(TableB$Description, TableA$Code) ]
# [1] "Apple"  "Banana" NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `elucidate::translate()` function, which provides a more readable syntax for the match() solution posted by [r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans).

```
tableA <- data.frame(code = c(001, 002),
                     Description = c("Apple", "Banana"))

tableB <- data.frame(Description = c(001, 002, 003))

tableB$Description <- translate(tableB$Description, old = tableA$code, new = tableA$Description)

tableB

> tableB
  Description
1       Apple
2      Banana
3        <NA>
```

The elucidate package can be installed with:

```
remotes::install_github("bcgov/elucidate")
```